# ! LaTeX Error: File `ucharcat.sty' not found

Tags: xetex, packages

How to solve this problem ?
Any command line solution!

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the `ucharcat` package. Details of package installation depend on the TeX system. Which one do you have? (MacTeX, TeX Live, MikTeX)

Comment: ucharcat is in miktex and texlive, so simply updating your tex system should fix it, although the package does nothing at all in xelatex so if you are using xelatex you can simply remove the `\usepackage{ucharcat}`

Comment: I use Tex Live ! Can you please provide the details of it ?

Answer (score 0):

After four years I had the same issue when I tried to export a jupyter notebook using `nbconvert`. The answer provided by David Carlisle did not help because I have so far I cannot disable the packages that the python package `nbconvert` use to export pdf files.

In my situation I use windows subsystem linux (wsl2) with Debian. I realized that the conflict comes from the fact that the default Debian distribution (9, strecht) installed with the Microsoft Store installs a latex version of 2016. So what I bassically did was:

- Know which Linux and LaTes versions are installed

```
# Check my linux and latex versions
$ cat /etc/os-release # or lsb_release -a
$ latex --version
$ xelatex --version
# Results: Debian 9, latex & xelatex from 2016
```

- Upgrade my wsl2 Debian distribution

```
# Backup my data. In a Windows Power Shell terminal:
PS C:..> wsl --export Debian my_debian_backup.tar
# In a wsl terminal. Edit the sources.list files to Debian 10 (Bullseye)
$ nano /etc/apt/sources.list 
# And change strecht for bullseye. The new sources would look like:
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
```

- Upgrade linux & uninstall all latex related packages

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt purge --auto-remove texlive*
```

- Install latex using the common `apt install` (or `apt-get`) command. And check the new versions.

```
$ sudo apt install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic
$ cat /etc/os-release # or lsb_release -a
$ latex --version
$ xelatex --version
```

However, as you may see, this involves upgrading Debian which might be risky. Perhaps the best way is avoiding using de standard Debian `apt` installation tool and [install](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) tex-live from the [source](https://www.latex-project.org/get/#google_vignette) . As also mentioned in the LaTex project.

I hope this post still can help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix so much as a patch.  Find the file from a repository and put it in the same directory as your document.